# High School Geometry Text?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

This year I will be teaching 8 hard-working home-educated teens a Geometry course.   Back in 1994-1999 I worked full time as a High School educator, taking a turn teaching everything from Pre Algebra through Basic Calculus, and Geometry was (and still is) my favorite.   I am wanting to buy (at abebooks or some such place) a stack of student books and a teacher's edition.  Recommendations?    In some ways the recent editions may be better.   In other ways . . .  not so much.  I recall being aghast as a teacher at how "dumbed down" the texts had become just in the few years between my being a high school student and a high school teacher.  And that was 20 years ago.  If you have a specific publisher and year (Prentice Hall 1989, as a random example) that you enjoyed using as a teacher, I'd love to hear your comments.

Comment: Try http://matheducators.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I don't know have any textbooks to recommend, but I was curious whether something interesting would turn up if I poked around what's used in some high school honors geometry courses (unfortunately, in the past 20 or 25 years I think "honors" has come to mean little more than what "college prep" meant 40 years ago), and I found [this interesting page of parent comments](https://www.berkeleyparentsnetwork.org/recommend/schools/BHS/honorsgeom). Anyway, for starters try googling "honors geometry" along with "high school".

Comment: I recently read somewhere (forgot where, but it wasn't on the internet) about the existence of a high school geometry book co-authored by [George David Birkhoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_David_Birkhoff). I haven't seen a copy of the book yet, but any serious attempt by someone as renowned as G. D. Birkhoff is very definitely worth looking into. See [**Basic Geometry**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0821821016) (3rd edition) and [**Basic Geometry - Manual for Teachers**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0821826921), both by George David Birkhoff and Ralph Beatley.

Comment: I'd recommend [advanced high-school mathematics by David B. Surowski](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~dbski/writings/further.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

How about ***[Lines and Curves](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780817641610)*** by Gutenmacher and Vasilyev (Springer, 2013); about this book:

> "Lines and Curves" is a unique adventure in the world of geometry. Originally written in Russian and used in the Gelfand Correspondence School, this work has since become a classic: unlike standard textbooks that use the subject primarily to introduce axiomatic reasoning through formal geometric proofs, "Lines and Curves" maintains mathematical rigor, but also strikes a balance between creative storytelling and surprising examples of geometric properties.

I didn't finish reading the book, but as to the parts I have read, I can attest to the summary. [Here](http://www.abebooks.com/9780817641610/Lines-Curves-Practical-Geometry-Handbook-0817641610/plp) is the book at AbeBooks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any particular curriculum to follow, the best textbooks in English are probably the ones commonly used in England during the period 1910-1960 approximately.

The most frequently recommended school books in bibliographies seem to be those by C.V. Durell and by H.G. Forder.

- A number of Durell's textbooks can be found [here.](http://www.knowledge-dojo.com/) *A New Geometry for Schools* is for beginners. *Modern Geometry* is more advanced.
- Forder wrote *A School Geometry* and *Higher Course Geometry*. I only know the latter book, which is more advanced, but I believe they're both aimed at high-achieving students.

Kiselev's [*Geometry*](http://www.sumizdat.org/geom1.html) was recently translated from Russian under the titles *Planimetry* and *Stereometry*. I think the textbook is relatively good, but unfortunately, the translation is poor, as it was done by a non-native speaker of English.

In French, I would recommend the series by Hémery and Lebossé. In Russian, the books by Pogorelov are good, as well as the ones by Aleksandrov, Verner and Ryzhik (for students in so-called "mathematical schools").