# Rigorous and succinct high school geometry book

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

Can somebody suggest a high school geometry book written like Spivak's calculus book, assuming no previous knowledge.

Comment: A possible such text is the book co-authored by G. D. Birkhoff that I mentioned in a comment at [High School Geometry Text?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402566/high-school-geometry-text).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Sorry. It's been a while. I did see the book and was reading it. I was addicted to user-unfriendliness of Spivak's and the likes and took me three days to really start to appreciate the Birkhoff's book. Now I think it's really great. It goes to the heart of the subject in a way appropriate for high school level. Cheers

Comment: As I said in my other comment, I haven't seen a copy of this book yet, but given what you've said I'll definitely keep my eye out for it (at college libraries, used bookstores, etc.). However, I'm probably not enough of a geometry fan to order a copy online, but I might buy it if I see it at a used bookstore one day.